# free relatives and indirect questions

Tags: reported-speech, free-relative-clauses, questions-v-relatives

How do you distinguish a free relative from an indirect question? Both begin with wh-words. How are they different in meaning?
Are the following sentences examples of free relatives or indirect questions?

> Where he lives has been frequently asked.

> What he said that day has been frequently asked.

Answer (score 1):

An indirect question may use a clause like this.  You can tell it is a question because the person speaking is expecting an answer.

> Tell me what it is.

This is an indirect question.  It uses the imperative form, and expects a response.  The grammatical structure has a clause "what it is".  That clause has the same structure and meaning in:

> A cat is what it is.

But this second sentence doesn't expect a response and so isn't an indirect question.

In you examples, there is no expected response.  These are no imperatives or questions (direct or indirect)